# Redirecting to HTTP error documents without changing the request URL

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-codes

I'm trying to show an HTTP error document from a PHP page, but I would like the original URL to remain in the address bar to prevent search engine crawlers getting confused and to allow for reloading of the page in case it's a temporary issue.

I made a redirect function in PHP which goes a bit like this:

```
public static function Redirect($url, $code = '303 See Other') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 ' . $code);
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit(0);
}
```

If I want to display an error document, such as 403 Forbidden, I would do the following: `Redirection::Redirect('/errordocs/403.php', '403 Forbidden');` and it would work fine.

As I said though, the users URL will change to `/errordocs/403.php` which I want to avoid.

What I did try to do was remove the `header('Location: ' . $url);` line if the HTTP code was 4xx or 5xx. I was hoping this would then trigger Apache to display the correct document as I have my .htaccess set up to point to the relevant error pages (which works fine as it is).

What I actually got from doing this was the standard Google Chrome messages for when stuff breaks rather than my pretty custom error documents.

In a quick consensus, what's the best way of doing this now? Making it echo the page instead of redirecting?

Comment: I'd include the error page and exit the current script

Comment: @Raeki That's my solution so far if there's nothing technically better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just display the contents of the error html in case of an 4xx status code. Otherwise redirect:

```
public static function Redirect($url, $code = '303 See Other') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 ' . $code);
    if(strpos($code, '4') === FALSE) {
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    } else {
        include(get_error_page_file_name($code));
    }
    exit(0);
```

}

The above example will send proper HTTP status code, will display the contents of the error page and keeps your url in the address the same.

Comment: So basically just doing `include '/errordocs/{code}.php'` would be suffice for this solution then?

Comment: yes `include()` is better. `include()` is actually required if the error page contains php code.

Comment: I pretty much did this. I just added `ob_end_clean()` then `ob_start()` to make sure I don't get any output that was sent before the redirection call.

Answer (score 2):

I just did the same thing but since it's a 404 - not found - in my opinion - it's gone...

So I set my .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) - [G]
ErrorDocument 410 /error404.php
```

Now anytime someone hits the 404, it shows the pretty 404 page but stays on the present url

NOTE: here's a working example of the .htacesss file:
http://www.smdailyjournal.com/stackoverflow

And when you go to [Check the Header Codes](http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/) you will see it returns a true 410 - Gone message :)

Comment: Doesn't really matter, this htaccess solution is a good solution too

Comment: No, it wasn't it was asked what's the best way of completing the task. My solution addresses his request to keep the url show the proper code and display fancy pages.