# Website Redirect Alternative - Two URLs to use same code base

Tags: html, alias, cname

Currently I have a redirect setup in my domain host's dns for example2.com to goto example.com

I don't want it to redirect but rather stay as example2.com while displaying the exact content from example.com.  I don't want to copy the site's code between the two.  I want a single code base and both URL's to use the same code.

I am not sure how to achieve this using my web host's CPanel.  I thought I might be able to do it using cnames or aliases but that does not seem to work.  I am sure someone has had this experience before.

I believe this is a pseudo-programming question but if a mod decides this is the wrong stack please do move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

303 headers need to be sent with a new domain or in this case example.com, for apache or php related steps see these links:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url

[redirect to a page without changing the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199004/redirect-to-a-page-without-changing-the-url)

[Redirecting to HTTP error documents without changing the request URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006934/redirecting-to-http-error-documents-without-changing-the-request-url)

For explanations:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

Comment: inmotion is my webhost ;)  thanks ill follow these steps and see what I get.